# C programming passing function in if condition

Tags: c, function, callback

I'm writing simple function which returns maskable array of zeros and ones to array of numbers.

If number is a power of two maskable index will be one if not then zero.

It works fine without passing my simple function isPower() , but when I do pass it. weird things happen.

I want my code works with

```
if(isPower(nums[i]))
```

Without or condition

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *isPowerOf2(int num, int*nums,int *result);
int isPower(int num);
int main(void)
{
int array[]= {1,2,2,4,4,3,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,4};
int size=0;
int *result=NULL;
result=isPowerOf2(14,array,&size);

for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    printf("%i : %i\n",array[i],result[i]);
}
free(result);
printf("%i",size);
return 0 ;
}

int *isPowerOf2(int num, int*nums,int *result_num)
{
int *result=(int *)malloc(num*sizeof(int));

*result_num=num;
for(int i=0; i<num; ++i)
{
    if(isPower(nums[i])||!(nums[i]&nums[i]-1)) //this won't work  but when I use !(nums[i]&nums[i]-1) it works fine
    {
        result[i]=1;
    }
    else
    {
        result[i]=0;
    }

}
return result;
}

 int isPower(int var)
 {
 return ((var)&(var-1)==0)?1:0;
 }
```

Comment: You need to learn basics of `C` language and `OR` operator. Second operand of OR statement is NOT executed if first one evaluates to non-zero value.

Comment: I think you did not get my point I added second operand because without it won't work. I did add it to clarify my question, but I want code work without it. it supposed not be there.

Comment: You second operand `nums[i]&nums[i]-1`. Do you know the sequence of execution here?

Comment: try to compile code without || 
I mean if(isPower(nums[i])) it won't work However it is supposed to work

Comment: Focus on `isPower` function: `return ((var)&(var-1)==0)?1:0;` should be `return (((var)&(var-1))==0)?1:0;`

Comment: Yeah I got you. 
Thank you.

Comment: Also, clean it up.  If I can't immediately identify by eye the start/end of functions, I close-voe as 'Unclear' and move on to the next question.

Comment: My bad @MartinJames will do my best next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At times like this it pays to check what you're actually computing:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d %d\n",!(7&6),((7&6==0) ? 1 : 0)); //Not a power of 2
    printf("%d %d\n",!(8&7),((8&7==0) ? 1 : 0)); //Power of 2
    return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
0 0
1 0
```

If you think about it a bit, should make sense. Or does it? [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is killing you here. Why would the bottom right be 0?

Comment: Yeah, hope I give more attention next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Befare that 
(1 & 2) is a bitwise operand while
(1 && 2) is the logical operand.

So to be clear:
(1 & 2) == 0 is something completely different than !(1 & 2).